# How to change the style of a ListItem on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI and React for a project, and I have a component, that roughly looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onClickMethod = this.onClickMethod.bind(this);
    }

    onClickMethod() {
       // removed for brevity
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List>
                    {this.props.myData.map(pp => {
                        return (
                            <ListItem key={pp.name}
                                      style={styles.listItem}
                                      primaryText={pp.name}
                                      onClick={this.onClickMethod}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    listItem: {
        // removed for brevity, includes some styles
    },
    listItemClicked: {
        // removed for brevity, includes different styles than the ones in listItem
    },
};

MyComp.propTypes = {
    myData: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default MyComp;
```

Now the point is that I want initially all my ListItems to have the same style, namely the styles inside the `styles.listItem` object property. Then, if the user clicks a certain ListItem I want its style to change to the styles that are inside the `styles.listItemClicked` object property. Though, the rest of the unclicked ListItems should not change their style. Additionally, if the user has already clicked a ListItem and decides to click another ListItem, then I want the previously clicked ListItem to change its style to the default one that is inside `styles.listItem` and the newly clicked ListItem to get the `styles.listItemClicked` styles. So that, at any time only zero (initially) or one of the ListItems have the styles inside the `styles.listItemClicked`. Any ideas how to achieve this in React?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maintain a state which contain the index of the listItem which was clicked and use a simple condition to change style of that particular item like this

```
class MyComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Initialize a state which contain the index of clicked element (initially -1)
        this.state = { indexOfClickedItem: -1};
        this.onClickMethod = this.onClickMethod.bind(this);
    }

    onClickMethod(index) {
       // removed for brevity
       // When clicked then set the state with the index of clicked item
       this.setState({indexOfClickedItem: index});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List>
                    {this.props.myData.map((pp,index) => {
                        return (
                            <ListItem key={pp.name}
                                      // Use simple condition to change the style of clicked element
                                      style={this.state.indexOfClickedItem === index ? styles.listItemClicked : styles.listItem}
                                      primaryText={pp.name}
                                      onClick={this.onClickMethod.bind(this,index)}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use React `state` for something like this:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          currentSelectedItem: ''
        };
        this.onClickMethod = this.onClickMethod.bind(this);
    }
    onClickMethod() {
       // removed for brevity
       this.setState({ currentSelectedItem: pp.name });  // You must somehow manage to get the pp.name from the array here, assuming it is unique 
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List>
                    {this.props.myData.map(pp => {
                        return (
                            <ListItem key={pp.name}
                                      style={(this.state.currentSelectedItem === pp.name)?
                                        styles.listItemClicked : styles.listItem}
                                      primaryText={pp.name}
                                      onClick={this.onClickMethod}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```